# Bootstrap 4 Reponsive Line Breaks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm not finding anything in the documentatin to point me in the right direction here and I'm trying to avoid using `columns` since that could leave gaps between the wording.

I'm displaying the days date on the top of my site using `echo date('l') . "<br>" . date('F d, Y');`. Which displays the date like this but centered:

`Friday
November 03, 2017`

On small screens such as phones I'd like for it to display as `Friday November 03, 2017` without the line break.

I know I could easily just do this and achieve it but it creates gaps between the words since the columns are even in size:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
<?php echo date('l'); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
<?php echo date('F d, Y'); ?>
</div>
```

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

What I mean by gap is `Friday [gap here due to column space] November 03, 2017`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never see this question, but, my sugestion is this:

between dates, you can set a div clearfix, this div is only md size, so you make a hidden-sm and hidden-xs class like:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
       <?php echo date('l'); ?>
      <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm"> </div>


    <?php echo date('F d, Y'); ?>
       </div>
    </div>
```

it's correct? the clearfix div separate dates only on lg and md sizes.

Comment: Nice solution which worked. Only thing is `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` are no longer classes which exist on Bootstrap 4. I did use the corresponding new classes and it worked like a charm. The classes I used was `d-none` which is `display: none;` basically and the other was `d-md-block` which will display it on medium screens and above.

Comment: great, guy! The bootstrap is very very fast to front-end dev.

Comment: Oh I absolutely love it because of that. It makes it so much easier to develope.

Answer (score 2):

The more straightforward option is to use the display classes built-in to Bootstrap and hide the `<br />` based on screen size.

```
echo date('l') . "<br class='d-md-none' />" . date('F d, Y');
```

The use of columns or wrapping content in spans is overkill; just throw in a little display class and show/hide as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your question

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo date('l'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo date('F d, Y'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```